# CSS3 working with :before, :after of text to make inset and outset shadows

Tags: html, css, text, shadow

I'm trying to make two shadows of text - inset and outset. I've successfully made inset one and I'm trying to apply another white shadow - something like

```
text-shadow: x x x black, y y y white;
```

It looks a bit ugly so I've decided to make it via `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. I have some trouble:

[image: Bad text shadow]

```css
.CWE1 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "GillSansMT Bold";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.CWE1:before {
  position: relative;
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: transparent;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #6b4848;
  z-index: 1;
}

.CWE1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-text);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 1px white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span class="CWE1" data-text="Clean, Wonderful & Effective"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting collapsing issues. If you make `.CWE1`, `.CWE1:before`, and `.CWE1:after` all have `display: block;` it looks like it should accomplish what you're after.

```css
.CWE1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "GillSansMT Bold";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.CWE1:before {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: transparent;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #6b4848;
  z-index: 1;
}

.CWE1:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-text);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 1px white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span class="CWE1" data-text="Clean, Wonderful & Effective"></span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

`span` is an inline element, and if you make your span `inline-block or block` you can achieve what you are looking for.

```css
.CWE1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "GillSansMT Bold";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.CWE1:before {
  position: relative;
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: transparent;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #6b4848;
  z-index: 1;
}

.CWE1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-text);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 1px white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span class="CWE1" data-text="Clean, Wonderful & Effective"></span>
```

Comment: Okay, i've fixed my code as you've said, and the problem is still, but if i use button "Run code snippet" above, it works fine here. I use Mozilla 63.0.3 and Chrome 70.0.3538.110